# Finer control over Windows Phone map animations

Tags: windows-phone-8, maps

Windows Phone offers [SetView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207045(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_AnimatetoNewLocationandZoomMapViews) which allows you to animate map in different ways (map center, zoom level, panning). The animations are fine, but I haven't found a way to control the speed at which the animation happens. You can choose between three animation kinds: Linear, Parabolic and none, but they don't feel right in some cases - sometimes I need to move the pin just a bit, but do it fast and feel more like snapping to a particular point.

When using Linear or Parabolic animation kind, the map movement on short distances feels slow and lazy, on the other hand "none" is just too sudden - there needs to be at least some animation happening to allow the user to follow along. I understand that I'm asking for advanced stuff, but we're trying to build nice user experience here. Am I running into limitation of the platform?

Has anyone found any alternative way to animate WP map position? Is there a way to use built-in animations while having more control over speed?